# HAProxy with URL Prefix

Tags: haproxy

I need to add prefix to the URL and have it serve content from another URL .
Basically the HAProxy is running on another server and I have artifactory server on another . The artifactory listens on 8081 , so I hit artifactoryserverIp:8081
and artifactory homepage displays .
Now if I hit HAProxyServer/abcartifactory in browser , the URL should stay the same , but it should internally hit artifactoryserverIp:8081.

Here is  my configuration

```
frontend http
 bind *:80
 acl host_is_artifactory path_beg /abcartifactory
 use_backend artifactory-backend if host_is_artifactory

backend artifactory-backend
 reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(.*) \1\ /abcartifactory/\2
 server node1 artifactoryserver:8081
```

The output is that the browser says cannot find resource

Comment: You are prepending /abcartifactory to the path, but it is already there. Why? Also, `HAProxyServer/ABCartifactory` won't match `path_beg` with the capital letters in the browser path but lowercase in the proxy config.

Comment: The path_beg I have edited ,it was my typo. Regarding the prepending the prefix I'm not aware got it from some other forums ,but let know what should I aim to do ,so it just displayed the artifactory page , and stays with the same URL in the browser with prefix /abcartifactory

Comment: Can someone provide some pointers in this regrad ,still not resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 frontend http
  bind *:80
  acl host_is_artifactory path_beg /abcartifactory
  use_backend artifactory-backend if host_is_artifactory

 backend artifactory-backend
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)abcartifactory [/]?(.*)   \1\2
  server node1 artifactoryserver:8081
```

Comment: I get an error of: `'reqrep' : Expecting nothing, 'if', or 'unless', got '\1\2'.` I think there is an erroneous space after `abcartifactory`?